# Cordova Android ReactJS

Tags: android, cordova, reactjs, webpack

I have an issue with Cordova, when building an Android App. My `react-router` is never called when I open my cordova application and I cannot understand why.

My application is running perfectly fine, when I run it in my browser, but as soon as I build an application with cordova, the app only shows a white screen.

Here is my router:

```
export default (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route component={ App }>
      <Route name="Calendar" path="calendar" component={ Calendar } ignoreScrollBehavior />
      <Route name="Story" path="story/:id" component={ Story } ignoreScrollBehavior />
      <Redirect from="/" to="calendar" />
      <Redirect from="/index.html" to="calendar" />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

This is my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: ['./render.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/www',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [path.join(__dirname, "bower_components")]
  },
  node: {
    console: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          optional: ['runtime'],
          stage: 0
        }
      },
      { test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass!postcss'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|woff|ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    )
  ]
};
```

the `render.js` the entry point of my config file:

```
'use strict';

import './assets/scss/main.scss';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes.js';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

let history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and last but not least my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,
      minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport">
   <title>Calendar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app" class="container"></div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far I have figured out that my App, once it is build with cordova, does no longer call the router, therefore staying on the index.html wihtout any content forever.

So my question is how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by using the `hashHistory` in cordova. Since no server will serve your app from cordova (only file assets are being loaded and no rewriting can be done), the index route will not work, leaving your page blank because of a ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Adjust your `render.js` to include

`// since no server is used in the cordova env, use hashHistory there
const baseHistory = process.env.CORDOVA ? hashHistory : browserHistory;`

and adjust your webpack configuration to use the DefinePlugin to set the env variable

```js
const __CORDOVA__ = process.env.BUILD_TARGET === 'cordova';
...
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        CORDOVA: JSON.stringify(__CORDOVA__),
    },
}),
```